# Scrollview stop scrolling after [textview resignFirstResponder]

Tags: iphone, ios, textview, scrollview

it's not really easy to explain the problem but i will try:
I've a view witch scrollview and inside a lot of textview and textfield.

I want to scroll up and down when someone didbegin editing one field(or textview), so i have:

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification*)aNotification{
NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
o_scroolView.contentInset = contentInsets;
o_scroolView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

// If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
// Your application might not need or want this behavior.
CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activefield.frame.origin) ) {
    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activefield.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);
    [o_scroolView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
}
}
- (void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
o_scroolView.contentInset = contentInsets;
o_scroolView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
activefield=NULL;
}
```

like apple doc say. Offcourse activefield is a UIView* assigned via

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
NSLog(@"textFieldDidBeginEditing");
activefield=textField;

}

- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
NSLog(@"textViewDidBeginEditing");
activefield=textView;
}
```

ok everything work well except that when

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range 
replacementText:(NSString *)text
{

// Any new character added is passed in as the "text" parameter
if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
    // Be sure to test for equality using the "isEqualToString" message

   // [self EnablePrice:TRUE];
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    // Return FALSE so that the final '\n' character doesn't get added
    return FALSE;
}
// For any other character return TRUE so that the text gets added to the view
return TRUE;
}
```

The after resign scrollview (_scrollview) stop moving when i shift my finger up and down.

Thx in advice.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i added

[o_scrollview becomefirstresponder] after [textView resignFirstResponder];

Nvm sorry.